# ¿Por que da error al almacenar la imagen?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

por que da error al almacenar la imagen?
tengo este problema estoy usando laravel con livewire y utilizo el siguiente codigo para guardar mi imagen:

```
$this->imagen->storeAs('imagenes',date('YmdHis').'.png','publico'),
```

El detalle es que la primera vez que ejecuto el código me da este error:

```
Error
Call to a member function storeAs() on null
```

intento hacerlo de la forma como he hecho otros

```
$file->move(public_path().'/imagenes/',$nom_imagen);
```

el detalle es que me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Error Call to a member function move() on null
```

Yo sé que la imagen trae un archivo, porque yo lo estoy seleccionando en el momento o alguna forma de hacer que me valide si hay archivo? solo he intentando hasfile pero el detalle es que no lo estoy haciendo con el método $request ya que no lo estoy enviando así, simplemente llamo a la funcion

Comment: Si tienes este enctype `multipart/form-data` en tu form?

Comment: Hola, si lo tiene, pero no es como que si no hubiera dado tiempo que cargara la imagen, después de que me da el error, le doy guardar otra vez y guarda

Answer (score 0):

Para usar move, debe ser una instancia de Storage,

```
Storage::move('old/file.jpg', 'new/file.jpg');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#storing-files

Answer (score 0):

El error significa que `$this->imagen` es un objeto nulo.

```php
    // Debes recibir el parámetro $request en tu función
    public function elNombreDeTuFuncion (Request $request) {
        // Valida que la petición HTTP contenga una imagen
        if ( $request->hasFile('imagen') ) {
            // Obtén el objeto de imagen y asígnalo a una variable
            $imagen = $request->file('imagen');
            // Ahora sí puedes realizar operaciones con el objeto de imagen
            $imagen->storeAs('imagenes',date('YmdHis').'.png','publico');
            $imagen->move(public_path().'/imagenes/', $nom_imagen);
        }
    }
```

Comment: ElOP comenta esta al final de su pregunta: **solo he intentando hasfile pero el detalle es que no lo estoy haciendo con el método $request ya que no lo estoy enviando así, simplemente llamo a la funcion**

Comment: Mi error, he pasado por alto esa parte. Seguramente OP tiene un requisito técnico muy avanzado por el cuál no le es posible inyectar la dependencia Request.

Comment: Yo no lo he usado, pero conviene tener en cuenta que usa livewire y esa cosa también permite trabajar con el manejo de archivos

Comment: El detalle es que no estoy usando request, al usar livewire me salto el request porque uso componentes.

Comment: @MauEspaña ¿Ya revisaste la documentación de Livewire? Yo le eché un ojo y sí cambia mucho cómo se manejan las subidas de archivos

Comment: si, cambia lo se, pero hay un apartado que dice que usa lo mismo en upload files donde intente usar, porque yo no usaba mis subidas de archivo asi, pero viendolo no funciona.